# Delete key from ssh-agent on Mac OS X 10.6

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, ssh, ssh-agent

I'm trying to find a way to delete a single ssh identity from my Mac's ssh-agent, the ssh-add man page states the -d option does

```
Instead of adding identities, removes identities from the agent.
If ssh-add has been run without arguments, the keys for the default identities will be removed. 
Otherwise, the argument list will be interpreted as a list of paths to public key files and matching keys will be removed from the agent.
If no public key is found at a given path, ssh-add will append .pub and retry.
```

Since I have multiple keys I can't call them all id_dsa and I can't pass them as an argument since I wan't to delete the identities not the public keys.

So does anyone know another way to delete from ssh-agent on a Mac?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can open Keychain Access located in `/Applications/Utilities/` and navigate to your login keychain [image: login keychain].

Once there, you can delete SSH keys. They should look like SSH: /Users/your username/.ssh/*key name*
[image: SSH Key]